# Laravel Group and Show Popular Relation

Tags: mysql, laravel

If I have a `users` table with a column `country` and the user `belongsToMany` **Categories**, Is there a way I can group the users by country showing the most popular categories for each country?

For example:

**Users**

```
id | name  | country

1  | UserA | Canada
2  | UserB | USA
3  | UserC | Canada
```

**Categories**

```
id | Name
1  | Housing
2  | Cooking
```

**category_user**

```
id  | category_id | user_id
1   | 1           | 1
2   | 2           | 2
3   | 1           | 3
```

From the table you can tell that Housing is the most popular category in Canada. I can't seem to show that with code.

I've tried eloquent "with" function but it only just shows me category for a certain (1st?) user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Ersoy gave me a fantastic solution but it brought up a new problem which I didn't consider when posting the question. I have another table "payments" with a `haveMany` relationship where I sum all the `amount` column for each user. With the current join query, it duplicates the amount for each belongsToMany relationship resulting in wrong sum.

**Payments**

```
id | amount | user_id
1  | 500    | 1
2  | 200    | 2
3  | 150    | 1
4  | 100    | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return User::leftJoin('category_user as cu', 'users.id', '=', 'cu.user_id')
        ->join('categories as c', 'cu.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->groupBy(['country', 'c.name'])
        ->get([
            'users.country',
            'c.name',
            DB::raw('count(*) as total')
        ])
        ->groupBy('country')
        ->values()
        ->map(function (Collection $elt) {
            return $elt->sortByDesc('total')->first();
        });
```

it will print in the following format.

```
[
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "name": "Housing",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "country": "USA",
    "name": "Cooking",
    "total": 1
  }
]
```